# How can I associate error messages to the 'error' key in json response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to show the errors that can occur by uploading a file (file name, size).
I am using [an adapted version of Jquery Fiel Upload for Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example)

I need to have my error messages (validations)  associated to the 'error' key in my json response.

I guess I have to change the javascript to make it work.

json:

```
render json: {error: @upload.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
```

validations:

```
 validates_uniqueness_of :upload_file_name, :message => "File with this name is already in the database"
     
 validates :upload_file_size,  :inclusion  => {:in =>10.megabytes..20.megabytes}, :message =>"Too big or too small"
```

Javascript I use to upload the files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(function () {
          // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
          $('#fileupload').fileupload();
          // 
          // Load existing files:
          $.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action'), function (files) {
            var fu = $('#fileupload').data('fileupload'), 
              template;
            fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
            console.log(files);
            template = fu._renderDownload(files)
              .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'));
            // Force reflow:
            fu._reflow = fu._transition && template.length &&
              template[0].offsetWidth;
            template.addClass('in');
            $('#loading').remove();
          });
    
      });
    </script>
```

I have tried as well those things:
`json: => [{:error=> @upload.errors.full_messages }] }`
using this shows only the validation message but I need the status: as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

json:

```
format.json{ render json: {error: @upload.errors.full_messages}, :status =>422}
```

javascript (the cut-off of the main code)

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({       


        error: function(xhr){
          var errors = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).error
          alert(errors)         
        }
              });
```